# Hiding and showing a div when body height is more than the height of the viewport

Tags: jquery, css

I have been trying to hide and show a fixed div based on the screen height. It is for a mobile phone wherein when ever a scrollbar shows up, the div appears. This is for screens which are small.

This is the code that I am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
        jquery("textdiv").fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        jquery("textdiv").hide(100);
    }
});
```

You can see what I have accomplished on this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLjqK/).

Please let me know if there is anything else you would like from me. I am sure that the code I have used has some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is looking for something similar, I have worked further on Explosion Pills' answer and added extra code that makes the code run when ever the window is resized and the div disappears when someone scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

Check out the code below and JS fiddle after that...

```
$(window).bind('resize',function () {

    if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
        jQuery(".textdiv").fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        jQuery(".textdiv").hide(100);
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                    $(".textdiv").css("display","none");
                }else {
                    $(".textdiv").css("display","block");
                }
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NWusD/

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems to work fine, you just have some textual errors:

http://jsfiddle.net/NLjqK/1/

`jquery` -> `jQuery`

`textdiv` -> `.textdiv`

Comment: @user1865348 I also noticed that you use both `$` and `jQuery`.  You should really stick with just one

Comment: Thata a really good tip.. will keep in mind not to.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Selector you are using is looking for a tagname of `textdiv` which obviously doesn't exist. Add dot prefix for class in a selector

```
$(".textdiv").fadeIn(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a responsive design, css might be a better option that doing things in jquery.  You can use media queries as a "if/else" function on various attributes, in your case with screen width.  Please read about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).  And here's an example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  .yourclass {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried this, the problem is that I need something that shows and hides div based on the height of the body and the window height. this only changes heights based on window height.